# Row as subArray in MySQL Results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm Trying to get data from Releases Table and attach links to each release tried to do it with this query:

```
$links = $this->app->db->rawQuery("SELECT r.name, r.nfo, r.quality, l.*
                                    FROM Movies_DReleases r
                                    INNER JOIN Release_Links l
                                    ON r.id = l.release_id
                                    WHERE r.movie_id = ?", array($id));
```

and its giving result like this

```
Array
     (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => DVD Release
        [nfo] => This is description name NFO
        [quality] => DVDRip
        [id] => 1
        [release_id] => 18
        [host] => TC
        [language] => en
        [link] => google.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => DVD Release
        [nfo] => This is description name NFO
        [quality] => DVDRip
        [id] => 2
        [release_id] => 18
        [host] => TC
        [language] => de
        [link] => google.de
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => HDTVRip Release
        [nfo] => Second Release Description
        [quality] => HDTVRip
        [id] => 4
        [release_id] => 19
        [host] => TC
        [language] => fr
        [link] => google.fr
    )
............
```

links are with release description buy I need result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
          (
              [name] => DVD Release
              [nfo] => This is description name NFO
              [quality] => DVDRip
              [links] => Array
                         (
                           [0] => Array
                                      (
                                         [id] => 2
                                         [release_id] => 18
                                         [host] => TC
                                         [language] => de
                                         [link] => google.de
                          [1] => Array
                                     (...........)

     [1] => Array (....)
```

Its Structure of this tables, First Table Called Movie_DReleases:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| id   |  movie_id   | name |   nfo  |  quality |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

and its table called Release_Links

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id   |  release_id   | host |   language  |  link |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can't do this directly from the DB, but you can easily just modify your array afterwards.

Comment: there is not any way to do it without php foreach and queries for every release?

Comment: There isn't, no. What I suggest you do is create a new array of DVD releases with the key as `release_id`, and when you iterate through the links you add the link to the associative array (eg. `$releases[19]` would be the release with ID 19.)

Comment: I did it with this code http://ideone.com/r2YGCM thanks for suggestion

Comment: While it works, just be aware that this may execute 10000 queries every single time you refresh the page.